# Scaffold doesn't resize anymore when keyboard shows

Tags: flutter

Using the following code in my app should print the text "here" when I click on an input field and the keyboard is shown. When I use this code in my existing app it doesn't work. `didChangeMetrics` is not called. When using it in a new standalone app it works. 
Does anyone have an idea what can be the reason for this? I compared the AndroidManifest.xml files and they both contain:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="Framr"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

The only difference I can see is that I had to reploace `io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication` with `.Application` to register a firebase plugin.

This is the code of the widget:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    print("Here");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
          // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
          title: Text("test"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
          // in the middle of the parent.
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 40.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      )),
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Text('Name'),
                  TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 140),
                  Text('Bio'),
                  TextFormField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    maxLength: 150,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),

                ])),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          tooltip: 'Increment',
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        )
    );
  }
}
```